# How to display a PHP/HTML page in Flash

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-2

I have a PHP script which parses an rss feed and outputs the top 2 news items. I want to display these two news items in a standalone flash exe.

What is the best way to do it.

Thanks

Vinayak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002200.html) and pass the rss information to the flash application. Alternatively, use [HTTPService](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html). Example of how to work with PHP given [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html). RSS reader in flex using HTTPService example [here](http://amrkamel.wordpress.com/2008/02/16/flex-rss-reader-in-less-that-20-lines-of-code/).

Answer (score 1):

I dont have much experience in Flash but I would create an XML file (using the php) to hold the top 2 news items and make your flash application read this xml file. Here is a google searc page which will give you links about [how to read XML using flash](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=read+xml+using+flash&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a).